# Persistent Apple Sign-in with React Native

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, apple-sign-in

What's the recommended way to implement persistent Apple sign-in for React Native?

After signing in, Apple provides a userId and an identificationToken, both of which contain all the user information one could possibly retrieve from Apple.

Apple also exposes a getCredentialState function that determines whether the Apple sign-in credentials are still valid.

Couldn't I just check to see if the credentialState is valid each time a user opens up the app? If the credentialState isn't valid, they'll just have to sign-in again. Why is an access token and a refresh token necessary?

Thanks!